# Campos de Tabla MSQli Variables?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo que rellenar una tabla, con datos recogidos de un form. El problema es que yo no conozco qué Campo de la tabla se va a modificar, hasta que recibo la variable PHP. Exactamente:

```
$updatewin = "UPDATE live_chess SET Round1='1' WHERE Team='$TeamWin'";
```

Pero no sé que Round vendrá en el form via PHP, y tengo 50 campos Roundx!!!!
Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

Debes primero asignar un nombre al input donde ingresará el dato a capturar... Con un form method post luego en donde harás el query capturas la variable del form algo como $varinput = $_POST ['nombre del input'] ; luego usas la variable $varinput en el update algo como..

> $updatewin = "UPDATE live_chess SET Round1='$varinput' WHERE Team='$TeamWin'";

Comment: Estimado, gracias, eso no es problema, yo capturo los datos en variables PHP y las inserto en mysqli. El problema es, cuál es la columna a modificar, el Campo a modificar, el dato no es problema, es la columna de la tabla, tengo 50 columnas enumeradas desde Round1 hasta Round50, y en el formulario, por medio de un select, se escoge cuál de los 50 Rounds voy a modificar.
Digamos 
$updatewin = "UPDATE live_chess SET $Round='1' WHERE Team='$TeamWin'";
Donde $Round, puede ser cualquier columna de la tabla desde Round1 hasta Round50.
Entonces, puede ser variable el nombre de un campo o columna?

Answer (score 0):

Buscando buscando, encontré en google una respuesta que funciona muy bien. La comparto aquí, tal vez le sirve a alguien:

```html
$updatewin = "UPDATE live_chess SET $Round='1' WHERE Team='$TeamWin'";
```

Donde el nombre del campo de tabla, $Round es una variable PHP obtenida del form.